# ksh script to execute a piped command and looping over the results

Tags: ksh

I need to run a long piped command in ksh like this

```
cmd='ps -e -o args | /usr/bin/grep abcde | /usr/bin/grep -v grep'
```

Then execute this command.
And then loop over the results. 
So I am trying the above line and then

```
$cmd | while read $arg1 $arg2 ; do
    echo $arg1 $arg2
    blah  $arg1 $arg2
done
```

And there can be more than two args as well in the result.
I am not able to execute this and get the result what I want.
Can somebody please suggest what is wrong in this and how i need to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you *need* to store the pipline in a variable?

You might use a function instead:

```
find_process() {
    typeset search_pattern=$(sed 's/^./[&]/' <<<"$1")
    ps -e -o args | grep "$search_pattern"
}
find_process abcde
```

Note that `pgrep` does this better. See if it's installed on your system

Regarding the "two args" -- what is your question? What do you need to do with the `ps` results? If you're interested in reading a line into words, then

```
... | while read -rA words; do
    : do something with the array "${words[@]}"
done
```